# Ошибка исполнения `pyinstaller` при попытке запаковать приложение в один файл

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Директория моего проекта выглядит следующим образом

```
templates -
     - index.html
     - test.html
     - ..... .html
static-
     - css
         - index.css
     - js
         - index.js
```

Cобираю проект вот так

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "./static/*;static" --add-data "./templates/*;templates" main.py
```

При запуске собранного файла возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "app.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "starlette\staticfiles.py", line 57, in __init__
RuntimeError: Directory 'static' does not exist
[4600] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!`
```

Если переместить эти папки рядом с исполняемым файлом, то всё работает, но мне нужно, чтобы папки были уже упакованы в .exe-файл. Такое возможно?

Comment: покажите как вы обращаетесь к этим файлам в вашем коде